# Uniform convergence of the power series on $\mathbb R^-$

Tags: calculus, analysis, power-series, uniform-convergence

I need to determine whether the power series 
$$
\sum _{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{\ln \left(n\right)}\quad   x\in \Bbb{R} ,
$$
converges uniformly or not on the interval $[-1,0]$. I know already that the power series has a radius of convergence $R=1$, and I do also know that the primitive of the power series is continuous in $-R=-1$, i.e. the primitive is continuous on $[-1,1)$.

Comment: This is a version of Abel's theorem (see Theorem 8.4.1 in [here](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Analysis/Book%3A_Real_Analysis_(Boman_and_Rogers)/8%3A_Back_to_Power_Series/8.4%3A_Boundary_Issues_and_Abel%E2%80%99s_Theorem))

Comment: I see, that’s a good one. But unfortunately, I can’t use it, as it’s not a theorem in my textbook. What I do have is a Lemma:

“Assume that the power series
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_{n}x^{n}}$
converges when $x=b$, $b\neq0$. Then, the power series will converge absolute for all x just $|x|<|b|$. The power series converges uniformly on every interval $[-c,c]$ just $0<c<|b|$”

Maybe I can use that one?

Comment: No you can't use that... The behaviour of power series on the boundary of the interval of convergence is tricky, I doubt there's any easy workaround.

Comment: Ah, okay. But thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you could show convergence at $x=-1$,then abel's theorem will guarantee that it converges uniformly on $[-1,0]$.